# postgresql triggers after update

Tags: postgresql, triggers

The following function ,update_sessioninfo(), should only update changed columns. The New.* columns are being updated to some incorrect values after running:

```
update freeradius.radacct set acctsessiontime=25 where radacctid=3;
```

function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_sessioninfo() RETURNS trigger AS $radacct_update$
BEGIN
    -- update the updated records

       update freeradius.day_guiding_usage set  acctstoptime=New.acctstoptime,acctsessiontime=New.acctsessiontime,connectinfo_start=New.connectinfo_start,connectinfo_stop=New.connectinfo_stop,acctinputoctets=New.acctinputoctets,acctoutputoctets=New.acctoutputoctets,acctterminatecause=New.acctterminatecause where acctsessionid=Old.acctsessionid;

 RETURN NULL;
END;
$radacct_update$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The trigger is below

```
CREATE  TRIGGER radacct_update AFTER UPDATE ON freeradius.radacct
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN (OLD.* IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.*)
EXECUTE procedure update_sessioninfo();
```

Comment: _The New.* columns are being updated to some incorrect values_: the function does not attempt to modify `New.*` and it couldn't anyway because it's an AFTER UPDATE trigger (too late to change the values). By itself this function looks fine so it's not clear what is expected and what is obtained instead.

Answer (score 1):

`WHEN (OLD.* IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.*)` means that there's something changed => old row is different from new row, but when update happens it will update all columns of your table.

See examples and documentation here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createtrigger.html